# OpenXML C# Excel creation with LineChart

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I would like to generate a Chart image without using any third-party tool or win forms support.

I tried following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-insert-a-chart-into-a-spreadsheet

The generated Excel document is corrupted and the repair option deletes the drawingpart object.

Are there any other resources or sample code available to help me create a line chart using OpenXML and C#? Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The end goal is to generate a line chart using C# without any third-party library support.

Comment: Appreciate your time, edited the post. SO community inputs became an integral part of my dev work.

Comment: My trick with OpenXML. Create a spreadsheet in Excel and save it. Then add the feature you want (the line chart) and save it with another name. Now you have two XLSX files, and the only difference in the line chart. Find the _OpenXML Productivity Tool_ on GitHub and install it. It has a feature where you can difference two OpenXML files and it will show you the differences - both in C# and XML. Figure things out from there. It's also useful in figuring out the file corruption you get during development

Comment: That is promising. Trying it now. Thanks!